# Acceptance Testing with Requests Library (python)

Tags: python, httprequest, python-requests, acceptance-testing

I'm having issues writing an acceptance test for login functionality using the requests library. The login was implemented using post method and I have no way to directly alter a query string and manipulate the url. What I'm trying to do is manually submit the post data and have the page redirect to the page it would regularly go to if a user successfully logged  in. I would like to retrieve the html of that page and check for successful login, how would I do this?

This method fails:

```
data={'email': 'example@example.com', 'password': 'example'}

login_url="examplepage.com/signin"

request_data = requests.post(login_url, data, allow_redirects=True)

print request_data.content
```

This is what resp.headers returns:

`{'content-length': '1124', 'date': 'Sun, 14 Apr 2013 16:12:51 GMT', 'set-cookie': 'session="+udnwfCkuAuFGp9QKOiU1YS2X1s=?_fresh=STAwCi4=&_id=Uyc3XHhkZVx4Y2J3T1x4YjBceDkxeFx4MWNceGFhXHhkNFx4OTMhKVx4MGJyJwpwMQou&csrf=Uyc2Mzk0YjVjZjMzMGZkMTNkY2NiM2EzZTZkYzgyMjhkY2IwOWQ2NmM3JwpwMQou"; Path=/; HttpOnly', 'content-type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8', 'connection': 'keep-alive', 'server': 'Werkzeug/0.8.3 Python/2.7.3'}`

resp.content just returns the html of the sign in page:

```
    <title>Web App</title>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div>Web App: <a href="/home">Home</a>

            | <a href="/signin">Login</a>
            | <a href="/register">Register</a>

    </div>
    <hr>




<h1>Sign in</h1>


<form action="" method=post name="signin">
    <div style="display:none;"><input id="csrf_token" name="csrf_token" type="hidden" value="20130414164251##fd7e82d47974518d098b41cecf2a4452f890317f"></div>
  <dl>

  <dt><label for="email">Email Address</label>
  <dd><input id="email" name="email" type="text" value="example@example.com">

  </dd>


  <dt><label for="password">Password</label>
  <dd><input id="password" name="password" type="password" value="">

  </dd>

  </dl>
  <p><input type="submit" value="Sign in">
</form>

<a href="/login"> Click here to sign in using your Google, Yahoo, AOL, Flickr, or another OpenID account. </a>


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How is it that it fails? What comes back from the print command?

Comment: It wasn't redirecting, it would just return the sign in page html.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to login to a page I'd suggest creating session despite of standalone requests. If you send data correctly You should retrieve some session cookie. I'd check it to be sure that you're logged in. As the script logs in and it gets cookie, it should also retrieve Location header containing target page. Try something like this:

```
import requests
data={'email': 'example@example.com', 'password': 'example'}
login_url="examplepage.com/signin"
s = requests.session()
resp = s.post(login_url,data)
#now s.cookies should contain session cookie if properly logged in
target = s.get(resp.headers['Location'])
```

But I think the problem may be about session.

Comment: I did some more research, apparently disabling CSRF isn't the smartest idea. Can you give me more details about the method you suggested? I tried your code but I get this: `requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL u'None': No schema supplied`

Comment: It seems that response doesn't contain Location header. That means your response header's status code is not 301 which is http redirection. Could you please show your response.headers and response.content?

Comment: Headers certainly show that post is correct, you receive 'set-cookie' with session cookie. Maybe the redirection is called by html meta tag. Does the response contain something like: `<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; url=example.com/"; />` ?

Comment: I see. That's strange, because the script acts same as the web browser now. Have you compared response.headers with http headers received by the browser? I would delete current page cookies so the answer should similar to one collected by the script.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. How would I check the headers received by the browser? Do you mean that I should clear the cookies from my browser?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28209/discussion-between-michal-and-mike)

Answer (score 0):

My solution was changing the `CSRF_ENABLED` variable from **True** to **False** in my app's `config.py` file. The above code actually worked once I changed this setting. I am hosting on Heroku by the way.

Comment: Read up on CSRF, this is not suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I did this:

```
    if auth == True:
        # fetch the login page in order to get the csrf token
        cookieHandler = urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor()
        opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPSHandler(), cookieHandler)
        urllib2.install_opener(opener)

        login_url = URL
        login_page = opener.open(login_url)

        # attempt to get the csrf token from the cookie jar
        csrf_cookie = None
        for cookie in cookieHandler.cookiejar:
            if cookie.name == 'csrftoken':
                 csrf_cookie = cookie
                 break
        if not cookie:
            raise IOError("No csrf cookie found")

        # login using the usr, pwd, and csrf token
        login_data = urllib.urlencode(dict(
            username = username, password = password,
            csrfmiddlewaretoken = csrf_cookie.value))

        req = urllib2.Request(login_url, login_data)
        resp = urllib2.urlopen(req)
        contents = resp.read()

    target_download = target_url
    status_code = urllib2.urlopen(target_download).getcode()
    our_document = urllib2.urlopen(target_download).read()
    return status_code, our_document
```